# Django Database Caching

Tags: python, django, django-cache

I'm working on a small project, and I wanted to provide multiple caching options to the end user. I figured with Django it's pretty simplistic to swap memcached for database or file based caching. My memcached implementation works like a champ without any issues. I placed time stamps on my pages, and curl consistently shows the older timestamps in locations where I want caching to work properly. However, when I switch over to the database caching, I don't get any entries in the database, and caching blatantly doesn't work.

From what I see in the documentation all that should be necessary is to change the backend from:

```
CACHE_BACKEND = 'memcached://localhost:11211'
```

To:

```
CACHE_BACKEND = 'db://cache_table'
```

The table exists after running the required manage.py (createcachetable) line, and I can view it just fine. I'm currently in testing, so I am using sqlite3, but that shouldn't matter as far as I can tell. I can confirm that the table is completely empty, and hasn't been written to at any point. Also, as I stated previously, my timestamps are 'wrong' as well, giving me more evidence that something isn't quite right.

Any thoughts? I'm using sqlite3, Django 1.0.2, python 2.6, serving via Apache currently on an Ubuntu Jaunty machine. I'm sure I'm just glossing over something simple. Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 8):

According to the documentation you're supposed to create the table not by using syncdb but with the following:

```
python manage.py createcachetable cache_table
```

If you haven't done that, try and see if it doesn't work.

Comment: Was a typo, sorry. Corrected it

Comment: @lemonad  Once I update something and then call same API updated data is not getting it's serving from cached database, how should I handle this issue?

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare This question is from 2009 so it is probably better you open a new question.

In general though, you have to provide your own cache invalidation scheme. That is, if you update something, you have to delete the value from the cache manually. Otherwise, the old value will still be served.